# Can i add only a login function to my app? Swift/Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, authentication, logic

I have an app in which i want to only add a logIn button. No signUp.

**I am thinking of it like this please tell me if this can work?**

SaaS based. So if a business wants to use app, they must sign up on website. 
once they do, they can download app where i will give them their logIn Credentials.

Therefore if someone downloads my app from the app store they cannot register unless they are a SaaS customer. Only LogIn with the credentials i provide after signing up and paying for the service.

**This being said,** if this is doable. i used the parse swift signup code to get my classes working on parse.com

If i go into the users class, i can add new usernames and passwords. (Great!)

If i delete the SignUp code now from my app, and add the LogInUserinBackground code will it still work for logging in users so long as i add their credentials on the Back-End?

Thank you for all responses! Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that can and will work.

You can of course remove the ability to create users via the app and only support the creation via the application. Just set the user up via the website, assign the username and password and you are ready to go. Of course you have to create some kind of login form inside the app - what you **cannot** do is customize the application one user *downloads* to one specific SaaS customer so that he gets logged in fully automatically. At least once the user has to enter the user credentials in the app.

And as far as I am informed that is even allowed by the app store guidelines - you only have to make sure apple gets a demo account when submitting the app in the end.

Comment: Sorry about the duplicate question. Just so i fully understand the what you **cannot** do sentence. You mean all customers of the SaaS product have to have the same access. I basically can not offer different levels of service?

Comment: @MatthewEhrlich I clarified it a tiny bit - what I meant was that you cannot customize the actual downloaded app version for one customer. Everybody that wants to use the app has to manually login first (at least once).

Comment: i probably seem confused because i did too much thinking today. But when you say "everybody that wants to use the app..." If you signed up for my SaaS on my website, then i ask you to download the app. Then i say ok your username is : abcd and your password is: qwerty. Then you go to log in.. This will work right? i apologize for my confusion, i just want to be clear. Thanks luk

Comment: @MatthewEhrlich sorry for the late response: Yes!